# How to turn socket into ssl socket in asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to build a client with Socks-5 and SSL.

1. I build a connection with Socks-5 server.
2. I build the SSL connection.

I think I need a socket in step one. And I need a SSL socket in step two.

How can I turn a socket into a SSL socket in asio?

Comment: SSL is a _transport layer_ and sits on top of a regular socket.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious thank you. I just want to support the sock5 and SSL function.

Comment: Then it will look something like _program <-> socks5 <-> ssl <-> socket_. Raw sockets won't be useful in this situation. If this is what you want you might want to update your question to reflect that.

Comment: I fix it by:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943541/boost-asio-how-to-read-write-on-a-ssl-socket-that-doesnt-use-ssl?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943541/boost-asio-how-to-read-write-on-a-ssl-socket-that-doesnt-use-ssl?rq=1